# Installed cron scheduler but I see now that cron is having issues

Tags: magento-1, cron, crontab

I'm looking at the timeline & I see that cron keeps stopping & the cron jobs are not running.

I get this message "**Last heartbeat is older than one hour. Please check your settings and your configuration!**"

Can anyone help?

[image]
[image]

Comment: check your admin cron configuration.

Comment: @kunj I did but I don't see anything wrong. I just posted a screenshot.

Comment: Please share the result of from putty crontab -l 
Also run this command and share the result 
ps aux | grep -E "indexer|cron"

Answer (score 0):

Well because of my low rep i coudn't comment on your question.
Please check following logs:

1. exception.log
2. system.log
3. cron.log

All those are visible under default route /var/www/html/var/log/{Specific.log}

I assume you installed the AOE Scheduler https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler Please update the whole module if you coudn't find anything by those 3 Steps

Our Reason was a thrown exception during a created scheduler task which paused the process.